# PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am wanting to store a Rownum as a variable rather than use a costly Join. 
I need to get this from a Select statement as the Rownum will be different on various environments so it cannot be a literal string in the code.

For context, this query is executed on Oracle Siebel CRM schema and it retrieves some products of specific type and attributes.

I tried using the following SQL code in Toad and Oracle SQL Developer, however I am getting the following error:

> PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement

Here is the code

```
    DECLARE
    PROD_ROW_ID varchar(10) := NULL;
BEGIN
    SELECT ROW_ID INTO VIS_ROW_ID FROM SIEBEL.S_PROD_INT WHERE PART_NUM = 'S0146404';

    BEGIN
        SELECT rtrim(VIS.SERIAL_NUM) || ',' || rtrim(PLANID.DESC_TEXT) || ',' ||
               CASE
               WHEN PLANID.HIGH = 'TEST123'
               THEN
                   CASE
                   WHEN to_date(PROD.START_DATE) + 30 > sysdate
                   THEN 'Y'
                   ELSE 'N'
                   END
               ELSE 'N'
               END
               || ',' || 'GB' || ',' ||
               rtrim(to_char(PROD.START_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
        FROM SIEBEL.S_LST_OF_VAL PLANID
            INNER JOIN SIEBEL.S_PROD_INT PROD
                ON PROD.PART_NUM = PLANID.VAL
            INNER JOIN SIEBEL.S_ASSET NETFLIX
                ON PROD.PROD_ID = PROD.ROW_ID
            INNER JOIN SIEBEL.S_ASSET VIS
                ON VIS.PROM_INTEG_ID = PROD.PROM_INTEG_ID
            INNER JOIN SIEBEL.S_PROD_INT VISPROD
                ON VIS.PROD_ID = VISPROD.ROW_ID
        WHERE PLANID.TYPE = 'Test Plan'
              AND PLANID.ACTIVE_FLG = 'Y'
              AND VISPROD.PART_NUM = VIS_ROW_ID
              AND PROD.STATUS_CD = 'Active'
              AND VIS.SERIAL_NUM IS NOT NULL;
    END;
END;
/
```

Comment: In your second sql statement doesn't have INTO clause which is causing the error.

Comment: @Polppan  So the INTO should be in the second statement rather than the first, if so. How does my variable get set?

Comment: See my answer and let me know if that suffices.

Comment: In PL/SQL you can't use traditional `SELECT` query.

Comment: Will this work if I run it on SQL Plus console?

Comment: @loosebruce It should.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In PLSQL block, columns of select statements **must be** assigned to variables, which is not the case in SQL statements.

The second BEGIN's SQL statement doesn't have INTO clause and that caused the error.

```
DECLARE
   PROD_ROW_ID   VARCHAR (10) := NULL;
   VIS_ROW_ID    NUMBER;
   DSC           VARCHAR (512);
BEGIN
   SELECT ROW_ID
     INTO VIS_ROW_ID
     FROM SIEBEL.S_PROD_INT
    WHERE PART_NUM = 'S0146404';

   BEGIN
      SELECT    RTRIM (VIS.SERIAL_NUM)
             || ','
             || RTRIM (PLANID.DESC_TEXT)
             || ','
             || CASE
                   WHEN PLANID.HIGH = 'TEST123'
                   THEN
                      CASE
                         WHEN TO_DATE (PROD.START_DATE) + 30 > SYSDATE
                         THEN
                            'Y'
                         ELSE
                            'N'
                      END
                   ELSE
                      'N'
                END
             || ','
             || 'GB'
             || ','
             || RTRIM (TO_CHAR (PROD.START_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
        INTO DSC
        FROM SIEBEL.S_LST_OF_VAL PLANID
             INNER JOIN SIEBEL.S_PROD_INT PROD
                ON PROD.PART_NUM = PLANID.VAL
             INNER JOIN SIEBEL.S_ASSET NETFLIX
                ON PROD.PROD_ID = PROD.ROW_ID
             INNER JOIN SIEBEL.S_ASSET VIS
                ON VIS.PROM_INTEG_ID = PROD.PROM_INTEG_ID
             INNER JOIN SIEBEL.S_PROD_INT VISPROD
                ON VIS.PROD_ID = VISPROD.ROW_ID
       WHERE     PLANID.TYPE = 'Test Plan'
             AND PLANID.ACTIVE_FLG = 'Y'
             AND VISPROD.PART_NUM = VIS_ROW_ID
             AND PROD.STATUS_CD = 'Active'
             AND VIS.SERIAL_NUM IS NOT NULL;
   END;
END;
/
```

**References**

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#LNPLS00601
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/selectinto_statement.htm#CJAJAAIG
http://pls-00428.ora-code.com/

Comment: Thanks it is running now!

Comment: Could you explain what the fix is so I can understand, thanks

Comment: To complement this answer, if you don't need to use INSERT_INTO then you have to add this before the SELECT:  'open MYCURSOR for'