# how to declare date variable in sql using toad for oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date, variables, toad

I'm getting a "PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement" when I try to run the following code in sql in TOAD. I need to be able to declare the date variable at the beginning of the code since it will change when I run the report.

```
declare
report_date date;
begin
report_date := to_date('09/12/2017','mm/dd/yyyy');
  SELECT   IDMOWNER.INDX_WT.ISSUE_NM,
           IDMOWNER.INDX_WT.SEDOL_ID,
           IDMOWNER.INDX_WT.ISSUE_SYM_ID,           
           IDMOWNER.INDX_WT.ISSUE_ID
    FROM   IDMOWNER.INDX_WT
   WHERE   ( ( (IDMOWNER.INDX_WT.RPT_DT) = TO_DATE (report_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy'))
            AND ( (IDMOWNER.INDX_WT.INDX_SRC_CD) = 'SOD')
            AND ( (IDMOWNER.INDX_WT.INDX_SYM_TX) = 'NQSSFB'))
ORDER BY  IDMOWNER.INDX_WT.RPT_DT,
          IDMOWNER.INDX_WT.ISSUE_SYM_ID,
          IDMOWNER.INDX_WT.MKT_VALUE_AM DESC;      
end;
```

Comment: Declaring a date variable is not your issue. You need `into variable_list ...` before `FROM`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25486543/pls-00428-an-into-clause-is-expected-in-this-select-statement)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to run this query and get the output, a PL/SQL block is probably not your best choice. I think your question is actually [a duplicate of this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564283/how-to-declare-variable-and-use-it-in-the-same-sql-script-oracle-sql).

I would suggest using a substitution variable, like this:

```
def report_date = '09/12/2017'

SELECT   IDMOWNER.INDX_WT.ISSUE_NM,
         IDMOWNER.INDX_WT.SEDOL_ID,
         IDMOWNER.INDX_WT.ISSUE_SYM_ID,           
         IDMOWNER.INDX_WT.ISSUE_ID
  FROM   IDMOWNER.INDX_WT
 WHERE   ( ( (IDMOWNER.INDX_WT.RPT_DT) = TO_DATE (&report_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy'))
          AND ( (IDMOWNER.INDX_WT.INDX_SRC_CD) = 'SOD')
          AND ( (IDMOWNER.INDX_WT.INDX_SYM_TX) = 'NQSSFB'))
ORDER BY  IDMOWNER.INDX_WT.RPT_DT,
          IDMOWNER.INDX_WT.ISSUE_SYM_ID,
          IDMOWNER.INDX_WT.MKT_VALUE_AM DESC;
```