# How return table data in a PL SQL?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to create a PL SQL that returns a table but it doesn't work

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProcedure 
AS
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM MyTable
END
```

What is wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SELECT` statement `END` procedure are need to end with `;`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MyProcedure 
(
   P_Column1 OUT INTEGER,
   P_Column2 OUT VARCHAR2,
   P_COlumn3 OUT FLOAT
)
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3 
   INTO P_Column1, P_Column2, P_Column3 
   FROM MyTable
   WHERE <Condition>;
END;
/
```

with usage of `CURSOR`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GET_ONESET_CUSTOMERINFO
(
   CURSOR_ IN OUT TYPES.REF_CURSOR
)
AS
BEGIN
   OPEN CURSOR_ FOR
      SELECT * FROM MyTable
      WHERE <condition>;
END;
```

Please find some more examples in [this page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21043_01/bi.1111/e16630/app_ds_from_sp.htm)

Comment: LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
6/4       PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:     ; 
Errors: check compiler log

Comment: 5/5       PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
Errors: check compiler log

Comment: @jnoguerm I guess columns of select statements must be assigned to variables. Please refer [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25486681/2451726)

Comment: Could you put a simple example please? I can't make it work.

Comment: @jnoguerm I have updated the asnwer with `OUT` param of different data types and `SELECT ... INTO`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193474/discussion-between-arulkumar-and-jnoguerm).